# Strange readLine() and print() behavior that causes delay in print() although print() was called first in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, stdout, readline

I have a strange problem that I cannot seem to understand and that appears to not have been covered at all on the internet (either that or I don't know what to look for). If there's another answered question on this, please direct me towards it.

Consider the following sample of code:

```
while true {
    print("enter some text: ", terminator: "");
    if let input = readLine(strippingNewline: true)?.lowercased() {
        print("received \(input)")
    }
}
```

One would infer that the output should be:

```
enter some text: blah blah
received blah blah
enter some text:
```

And so on. However, the following output is what I receive:

```
blah blah
enter some text: received blah blah
```

In the above, I need to enter some text and press return *before* the "enter some text" prompt appears, which seems off because `print()` for the prompt was called *before* `readLine()`, but the order in which they are executed is reversed.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why the `readLine()` call appears to be delaying the initial "enter something..." `print()`. Is there a reason for this behavior and/or is there anything I can do to correct it to derive the expected output?

Comment: that's how a stack overflow looks likes ...

Comment: @nullqube could you please add more details?

Comment: apparently that what happens when you enter empty line, removing terminator:"" will fix it. looks ok?

Comment: it's because you run your code in Xcode at terminal it's work just fine.

Comment: Is there any reason why removing terminator: "" fixes the issue?